# python html parsing

Tags: python, html

i need do some html parsing use python .if i have a html file like bellow:

```
《body》
   《div class="mydiv"》
      《p》i want got it《/p》
      《div》
           《p》 good 《/p》
           《a》 boy  《/a》
      《/div》
   《/div》
《/body》
```

how can i get the content of 《div class="mydiv"》 ,say , i want got .

```
      《p》i want got it《/p》
      《div》
           《p》 good 《/p》
           《a》 boy 《/a》
      《/div》
```

i have try HTMLParser， but i fount it can't.
anyway else ? thanks!

Comment: I'm looking at the **Related** section on the right, and...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With BeautifulSoup it is as simple as:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    html = """
      <body>
        <div class="mydiv">
          <p>i want got it</p>
          <div>
            <p> good </p>
            <a> boy  </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    """

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    result = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'mydiv'})
    tag = result[0]
    print tag.contents
    [u'\n', <p>i want got it</p>, u'\n', <div>
    <p> good </p>
    <a> boy  </a>
    </div>, u'\n']
```

Comment: but, what i got is a list , how can it convert this list to a text file of html format?

Comment: from BeautifulSoup import Tag; st = ''.join([str(t) for t in tag if type(t) == Tag]). Then write it: with open('somename.html', 'w') as f: f.write(st). Something like this

Answer (score 4):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de). Or BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer lxml.html.

```
import lxml.html as H
doc  = H.fromstring(html)
node = doc.xpath("//div[@class='mydiv']")
```