# How to add a width attribute to each img tag using a django template filter?

Tags: html, django, parsing, dom

When displaying the body of some articles in my site in an rss reader, they are full width. I wish to add a width attribute to all images when used in the rss feed, preferably using a filter since I'm using a template to arrange the body among some other elements.

I wrote the following method, as a test:

```
try:
    _parser = minidom.Text()
    _parser.data = obj.body
    _xml = _parser.toxml(encoding='UTF-8')
    _return = minidom.parseString(_xml)
    _images = _return.getElementsByTagName('img')
    print "============= This is what I found: ============="
    #print _images
except ExpatError as (e):
    print "============= This is what I found: ============="
    print ErrorString(e.code)
```

But the output looks like this:

```
============= This is what I found: =============
syntax error
============= This is what I found: =============
not well-formed (invalid token)
============= This is what I found: =============
syntax error
============= This is what I found: =============
syntax error
============= This is what I found: =============
syntax error
============= This is what I found: =============
syntax error
(and so on, there are no working cases)
```

So maybe my method is wrong completely, hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can parse all valid HTML with XML parser.

Please look at [python html parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198107/python-html-parsing) for various ways of parsing html.